# CoffeeScript map object to class instance

Tags: javascript, class, object, coffeescript

Is there any way to map object received from server as a JSON to  class instance in CoffeeScript?

I have a lot of cases where my JSON is:

```
{
  id:   '123'
  name: 'wojtek'
  age:  24
}
```

and my coffee class is:

```
class Person
    constructor: (id, name, age) ->
```

How to directly map JSON to class instance without assigning each property separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest rewriting your constructor to accept a single object, e.g.:

```
class Person
  constructor: (@props) ->
```

or

```
class Person
  constructor: ({@id, @name, @age}) ->
```

After that you'll be able to map your JSON to class instance simply by passing it to the constructor:

```
person = new Person data
```

Comment: OMG, that's.. awesome!